# Why doesn't infinite recursion hit a stack overflow exception in F#?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

I know this is somewhat the reverse of the issue people are having when they ask about a stack overflow issue, but if I create a function and call it as follows, I never receive any errors, and the application simply grinds up a core of my CPU until I force-quit it:

```
let rec recursionTest x =
    recursionTest x

recursionTest 1
```

Of course I can change this out so it actually does something like this:

```
let rec recursionTest (x: uint64) =
    recursionTest (x + 1UL)

recursionTest 0UL
```

This way I can occasionally put a breakpoint in my code and see the value of x is going up rather quickly, but it still doesn't complain. Does F# not mind infinite recursion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `recursionTest` function is tail recursive, which means all recursive calls occurs in the 'tail position' i.e. as the last action in the function. This means the F# compiler does not need to allocate a new stack frame for recursive calls, so no stack overflow occurs.

Tail recursion is a specific case of [tail call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), the tail call being to itself rather than some other function.

Comment: Thanks, that also explained an unmentioned question as to why VS wasn't showing more calls in the call stack window.

Comment: In fact I believe in this case the F# compiler will actually convert the code to a loop - there is actually no recursion in the compiled code.

Answer (score 4):

In general, F# emits the tailcall instruction that .NET honors:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.tailcall(v=vs.95).aspx

In some specific simple cases, like yours, F# rewrites programs that use recursion into equivalent programs using loops.

Comment: Probably would have seen this if I took an extra minute to throw the app into the IL Disassembler or the reflector. Thanks for the extra background info.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of [tail call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) and so the compiler is optimizing it into a simple loop. See this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/fsharpteam/tail-calls-in-f/

Try something like this:

```
let rec recursionTest x =
    recursionTest x + recursionTest (x * 2)
```